# "The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller" error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, removechild

Been struggling with this in multiple projects. I try to spawn enemies in a Flash game and perform cleanup by removing the out of bounds enemies.

Here's how:

enemyArray contains references to the spawned enemy objects.
enemyLayer is the movieclip that contains the spawned enemies.

```
  public function spawnEnemy():void
  {

    var mc:MovieClip = new Enemy();
    enemyLayer.addChild(mc);
    enemyArray.push(mc);


     for (var i:int = 0; i<=enemyArray.length-1;i++)
     {
        enemyArray[i].z-=30; //Moves the enemies

        if (enemyArray[i].z <=-400) //performs cleanup
        {

                    enemyLayer.removeChild(enemyArray[i]);
        }

     }

   }
```

But I get this error

> The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

What am I doing wrong?

I've tried: removeChild(enemyArray[i]) as well, removing the enemyLayer reference, but get the same error.

Comment: Show us how and where you creating enemyLayer and enemyArray objects.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove your items from the array after you removed them from the display list

```
    if (enemyArray[i].z <=-400) //performs cleanup
    {

                enemyLayer.removeChild(enemyArray[i]);
                enemyArray.splice(i, 1);//removing enemyArray[i] from the manager array
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That wouldn't resolve his problem Engineer, because if 'somehow' movieclip to be removed exists but in different container, it would not be removed.
I'd suggest doing this:

```
enemyArray[i].parent.removeChild(enemyArray[i]);
```

Although this is not the best way to do this and is quite bad code it helps me everytime I have a problem like this.

EDIT: Problem is that you're not modifiying your array object. You just add enemies you never remove them. That's why you get that error. Array contains an enemy which is already removed from the display list.

Comment: '`enemyArray[i].parent.removeChild(enemyArray[i]);`' code will throw 'Null pointer exception', because `enemyArray[i].parent` can be 'null' after removing `enemyArray[i]` from its `DiplayObjectContainer` .

Comment: I think you're right but you didn't have to downvote because of that :)

Comment: This is really weird. When trying this code:

    enemyArray[i].parent.removeChild(enemyArray[i]);

I get a null object error. However, tracing (enemyArray[i].parent) will return "Object MovieClip".

Comment: Look at my answer in on the EDIT paragraph. It's because you don't remove MC-s from the array. It will sometimes return null. If enemyArray[i] has already been removed from display list but it exists in the array. You will have to remove references from the array itself.

Comment: @Engineer it's unefficient because if the game goes on for too log the array will become really large and it will consume a lot of RAM. Just suspending the errors doesn't mean it's a good way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, about unefficiency. But the question was about exception, and about resolving that. If we will talk about efficiency, I will modify all parts of above code !!